# text wont show using <h> and <p>

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple art profile for fun, I have a banner and a navbar. I tried to put in text:

Welcome to my art profile. This profile contains all my artworks from the previous years.

But this wont show on my page.

I checked the padding of my instructio nand navbar, bot of them should not be in the way. These are the only 2 things added to the code. I simply want the text to appear on the page.

Comment: This is the code for the text (didnt appear in my post for some reason)
<div id="main-content">
        <div>
    <h>Welcome to my art profile. This profile contains all my artworks from the previous years.</h>
</div>

The CSS code of the div
   }

        div#main-content {
            padding-top: 30px;
         
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, first off, add your code between 3 backticks (`). I looked at what I saw when you can edit an answer, and this is the code I saw:

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div>
    <h>Welcome to my art profile. This profile contains all my artworks from the previous years.</h>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, `<h>` is not a tag. You are probably looking for `<h1>`, `<h2>`..., `<h6>`.

This is your improved code:

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to my art profile. This profile contains all my artworks from the previous years.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, since you said there isn’t a lot that’s affecting your HTML, just post all the code. There is an “id” called “main-content”, which leads to believe some part of your code is causing the text not to show.